# How can I cast two spells at once, while knowing neither, so that I can use Contingency?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spellcasting

I'm trying to settle [an argument about Tiamat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163762/53359) (as statted in *Deities and Demigods*, apparently it's pages 93-94). To prove my point, I want Tiamat to have *Celerity* as a contingent spell. However, she knows neither spell and the wording of *Contingency* seems to make it clear that she essentially needs to cast both spells at once. How can this be done without learning these spells?

Note: She has access to [*Alter Reality*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#alterReality) and therefore I can safely say that just about anything is within her reach. An ideal answer will assume no more resources or cheese than what is given by a strict RAW reading of the Notes section of *Alter Reality*. Additionally, Tiamat must be the one to do it - no getting help from elsewhere. I promise that this is a very light set of restrictions.

As requested, the argument is over my claim that if Tiamat knows that a fight is coming, she has no reason to lose. My battle plan can be boiled down to "Contingent Celerity to move first, then *Persistent Time Stop* (via *Alter Reality*) to prepare for as long as you wish (years if need be), and then either win easily or accept that the enemy is optimised beyond belief".

Comment: What stats are you using for Tiamat? Are you aware that even when books claim to be presenting a god’s stats, those stats are often regarded as merely those of an avatar by later books, and that any god statblock are thus suspect?

Comment: What’s the argument you’re trying to settle?

Comment: @40355saysReinstateMonica It's in the comments here. I'm trying to prove that if you can lose a fight with access to Alter Reality, then you're either stupid or against an opponent who is far too optimised https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163762/53359

Comment: @KRyan Do I have more that one choice? Regardless, I'm definitely using the Deities and Demigods one that's intended for Tiamat herself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the wording for *contingency*:

> You can place another spell upon your person so that it comes into effect under some condition you dictate when casting contingency. The contingency spell and the companion spell are cast at the same time. The 10-minute casting time is the minimum total for both castings; if the companion spell has a casting time longer than 10 minutes, use that instead.

It sounds like you're arguing something like the following:

"I notice the *contingency* spell is cast at the same time as the spell you're using it with.  But it's not possible to cast two spells at the same time, so can *contingency* ever be cast by anyone at all?  Perhaps there is something special about the *contingency* spell, not explicitly stated in the rules, which lets you cast this spell at the same time as some other spell.  But perhaps this special thing about the *contingency* spell only works if you're casting the spell from memory, and not if you're using a divine power like *alter reality* to duplicate it as a standard action.  So perhaps wizards can cast *contingency* but Tiamat cannot."

This seems like a lot of supposition.  This DM probably would have interpreted that spell text loosely, so that casting the spells sequentially still works.

But if your DM is being picky about this, I'd recommend one of the following approaches:

- Use *alter reality* to create two spell scrolls, one of *contingency* and one of *celerity*.  Read them both at the same time, using *use magic device* to activate them.
- Use *alter reality* to create two *greater rings of spell storing*, a scroll of *celerity*, and a scroll of *heightened contingency*.  (The *contingency* spell must be heightened because the ring will decrease its caster level to the minimum possible, and we want to make sure that's still high enough to work with *celerity*.)  Cast the two scrolls into the two rings, then cast them out of the rings simultaneously.

Without knowing exactly how your DM has decided the "cast two spells at once if one of them is *contingency*" mechanic works, we can't say for certain if your DM will allow this.  But casting spells out of a *ring of spell storing* is very much like casting them from memory, so it seems like this should work, assuming your DM believes that it's possible to ever cast *contingency* at all.

Comment: RE: The argument says, "Perhaps there is something special about the *contingency* spell, not explicitly stated in the rules, which lets you cast this spell at the same time as some other spell." That "something special" is when the *contingency* spell description says, "The *contingency* spell and the companion spell are cast at the same time." That's a specific exception to the general rules. (Also, why does a *ring of spell storing* set a spell cast into it to the minimum caster level?)

Comment: To your second point: "Each spell has a caster level equal to the minimum level needed to cast that spell." It's a direct quote from d20srd.

Comment: I totally overlooked that! Thank you for your patience.

Comment: To your first point, I feel like the whole thing is basically an exercise in pedantry, and I don't feel like it would be fun for me to argue pedantry with you right now -- maybe you'd like to write your own answer? : )

Comment: I would, but I think your alternatives that use the alter reality ability to mimic *contingency*  and the companion spell *indirectly* are gold; I just don't think the answer should be down a DM for following the rules on *contingency* (such as they are) as it's one of the game's most powerful effects.